# Excel 2013 - recorded macro errors when changing page filter on OLAP based pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, olap, vba

This is the recorded macro:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").ClearAllFilters
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
    "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").CurrentPage = _
    "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region].&[some name]"
```

I have changed the actual name to "some name" for the purposes of the post.

I recorded that macro, then tried to run it.  I get an error:

> Unable to set the CurrentPage property of the PivotField Class

I have viewed other posts suggesting the use of

```
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim NewRSM As String

NewRSM = "some name"

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1")

With pt
    .PivotFields("[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").ClearAllFilters
    .PivotFields("[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").CurrentPage = NewRSM
End With

pt.RefreshTable
```

This also fails.

Answer (score 0):

This is too easy. Before posting an answer, I would highly recommend trying to debug your code a bit more in the future. Your problem is that you are trying to concatenate two strings, but you never close the first one. For example:

```
Dim Foo as String
Foo = "Apples"

Debug.Print "I like Foo!"
Debug.Print "I Like " & Foo & "!"
```

Try it out, and see if you can decipher what is happening.

Now for the solution. Same approach, minor fix:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
"[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").CurrentPage = _
"[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region].&[" & SomeName & "]"
```

Voila! To concatenate strings, you must use the variable in the same way you would use it elsewhere. That is to say, put the variable outside of the quotes, and concatenate the parts together.

Worth noting, both of these will only work if `pt.EnableMultiplePageItems = False` and the `PivotField` is a `PageField`. Additionally, the reason why your second version doesn't work is because an `OLAP` cube doesn't recognize `"some name"`. It must know the entire dimension, e.g `"[Foo].[Bar].[Baz].[Item]"`

While I'm here, I highly recommend avoiding the `ActiveSheet` reference. That will cause you issues down the line. I recommend naming your pivot tables as well. Heck, name anything you use. It makes your code easier to read.

Comment: Hi Brandon,  Thanks for your response.  Here is the recorded code.  It errors when I try and run it.                                                                                                                      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields( _
        "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").CurrentPage = _
        "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region].&[Craig]"

Comment: @ScanGuard Is the `EnableMultiplePageItems = False` set? Also, are you certain `Craig` is in the `Sales Region` dimension?

Comment: Hi Brandon.  The code is as actually recorded, so yes, Craig is in the dimension.  The EnableMultiplePageItems check box is not ticked.

Comment: Hi Brandon.  The code is as actually recorded, so yes, Craig is in the dimension.  The EnableMultiplePageItems check box is not ticked.

Comment: @ScanGuard the `.CurrentPage` property of a `PageField` only works when the `.EnableMultiplePageItems` is first set to false. Be sure as well that you are working on a page field and not some other kind of field (such as a row field). Page fields show above the Pivot Table in the top left. I would also recommend using the immediate window and breakpoints to try getting the `CurrentPage` of the pivot table. Debugging tools will be a great help when it comes to using Macros with OLAP cubes.

Comment: .EnableMultiplePageItems is set to false. The dimension is a page filter.  Please advise what I should type in the immediate window to assist with debugging.     The 2nd line is highlighted in yellow when running the code      ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region]").CurrentPage = _
        "[Location].[Sales Region - Location].[Sales Region].&[Craig]"